# Unable to access Ubuntu machine locally running an OpenVPN client

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm currently running an Ubuntu Server machine that is running an OpenVPN client using a tunnel connection. Even though I want the network data to pass through the VPN tunnel, I also still want to access the machine from the public network using port forwarding (to allow running a web server on the machine that is accessible away from home).

Using some posts on other forums I was able to set up some custom network tables and routes to allow some network on specific ports to go through my regular network interface. This works perfectly fine and all my network activity now goes through the VPN client by default and the network activity on the ports I specified now go through my physical network interface, allowing me to open a web browser and browse to this machine using port 80.

The problem I'm currently facing though, is that with these custom tables and routes I don't seem to be able to browse to the machine (eg. 192.168.0.110) locally on the same network anymore (eg. from 192.168.0.27). When I try to open a web browser and browse to port 80 on the machine I receive a timeout after some time. The interesting thing is that when I use my public IP-adress using port forwarding, I'm able to access the machine on port 80 just fine. When I remove either the custom table settings or the custom route for the 'no VPN' access, I'm able to access the machine locally again but this breaks the access from the public network.

I've been trying to find people online with similar problems but I don't seem to be able to find anything related to the issue I'm facing.

I'm getting the feeling that, since I've added these custom tables and routes, the response from the Ubuntu machine is redirected to the default gateway instead of directly to the computer that sent the request to the Ubuntu machine.

This is my mangle table configuration:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NhDh.png)

I use these commands to configure the rule and route for the table:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuTNz.png)

Does anyway have an idea what I'm doing wrong here and how I can accomplish being able to access the machine on port 80 from both inside and outside of my LAN?

**TLDR;** I've used custom tables and routes to allow some ports to be routed using my default gateway to allow access to the machine even though a VPN Client is running on the machine. For some reason this makes it impossible to access the machine on port 80 locally even though it's possible to use this port using my external ip-address and port forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I was finally able to solve this problem...

Since I was able to create a situation where the web server was accessible from LAN only and a situation where it was accessible only from the outside network, I started thinking whether there was a way to combine these scenarios in another way.

I'm using Nginx as the web server and found out that it's possible to run the web server on multiple ports! So I edited the Nginx configuration to run on both port 80 and 8090 and applied the tables, rules and routes described in the OP only for port 8090. I then updated the port fowarding rules of my router to forward outside port 80 to port 8090 on my LAN. I was VERY glad to find out that this fixes the issue completely as I am now able to access the server on port 80 from my LAN and port 80 using my external IP-address since it forwards this to port 8090, which contains the 'no VPN' rules.

I suppose there is a better way to fix this problem but for the time being I'm satisfied with the current solution.